# Comment model has replies, but reply cannot have replies

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating comments. Each comment can have replies, but replies cannot have replies. I have tried to perform this on serializer and views level, but nothing works.

model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='replies')
```

Serializer:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    episode = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['reply_to']:
            comment = data['reply_to']
            if comment.reply_to:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Нельзя отвечать на ответ')

        return data
```

Viewset:

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        try:
            episode = Episode.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('episode_id'))
        except Episode.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound

        serializer.save(episode=episode, user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: So, you are getting error or it adds reply to reply?

Comment: @OsmanOmar adds apply to apply, I have changed validation in serializer(see the question), now you can't add reply to reply, but during PATCH request, in order to change only content, brings error ```KeyError: reply_to```

Comment: Not `if data['reply_to']`, check with `if 'reply_to' in data`